# Applying a list of functions to a single variable

Tags: python

I'm applying three filters to a single data structure that holds my data *one after the other*. Can I do this more neatly? Like a single call to a class encapsulating the three filters or passing it from one filter to the other (more like a co-routine) The [latter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf&ei=dTkZUeG9A4XsrAfbxIDYDA&usg=AFQjCNE4C2E-kSH8E3D4jVcJFXClBmkKpg&sig2=P4JwH5pTU-2ULQ3yBVz0Ig&bvm=bv.42080656,d.bmk) looks rather scary so can I do it neatly with the former paradigm?

Example, 
**data_list** holds my data

```
def _filter1(elem):
    return elem < 0        

def _filter2(element):
    ...
def _filter3(element):
    ...

list = filter(_filter1,list)
list = filter(_filter2,list)
list = filter(_filter3,list)
```

I imagine this would be the simplest way to put it:

```
filters = [_filter1, _filter2, _filter3]
list = apply_filters(*filters)
```

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to explicitly return True or False in your first filter: `return elem < 0` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filters = (_filter1, _filter2, _filter3)
list_after = filter(lambda x: all(f(x) for f in filters), your_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [`functools.reduce`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
list = reduce(lambda acc, pred: filter(pred, acc), filters, list)
```

Comment: could you explain what this exactly means? 
acc(umulator) corresponds to the filters list and pred(icate) to the passed list right? Shouldn't it be the other way around. Thank you.

Comment: @ShyamSunder `acc` is the accumulated value of `list`; `pred` is the filter predicate e.g. `_filter1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [x for x in lst if _filter1(x) and _filter2(x) and _filter3(x)]
```

Using a function that combines all of the filters:

```
def apply_filters(lst, *filters):
    def _filter(elem):
        return all(f(elem) for f in filters)
    return filter(_filter, lst)

lst = apply_filters(lst, _filter1, _filter2, _filter3)
```

As a side note, don't use `list` as a variable name as it will mask the built-in.